Is persecution of the Church in the end times a qualifier for Babylon the Great in Rev 17?
In Jer 25:8, 9 God says something to the effect, “I will bring Nebuchadnezzar, king of Babylon against the land and the inhabitants and you will serve Babylon” as punishment for idolatry. Will the end times Babylon (Rev 18) be used to punish / persecute the church as Babylon was used in the OT? If so, then isn’t persecution of the church a qualifier for end time Babylon. If this is the US then the government will move into persecuting Christians if the US is indeed Babylon the Great.

Jer 25:8, 9 - Therefore this is what the LORD of Hosts says: ‘Because
you have not obeyed My words, behold, I will summon all the families
of the north, declares the LORD, and I will send for My servant
Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon, whom I will bring against this land,
against its residents, and against all the surrounding nations. So I
will devote them to destruction and make them an object of horror and
contempt, an everlasting desolation.


Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

Any application of the contents of the Book of Revelation to current events is necessarily a matter of opinion, which becomes off-topic on this particular website.

I would answer your question not in terms of Jeremiah but in terms of Revelation.
"And I saw the woman, drunk with the blood of the saints and the blood of the martyrs of Jesus"- ch17 v6
That verse certainly does identify "Babylon the great" with a campaign of persecution. Other details associate her with idolatry. She rests on a beast "full of blasphemous names", and her cup is full of "abominations" and "fornication". In the Old Testament, "abomination" is normally about the worship of other gods, and I would take "fornication" as a reference to spiritual infidelity. In other words, the essence of "Babylon" would appear to be that her preference for other gods moves her into hostile action against the Christian community. Persecution.
However, your final suggestion is a circular argument, because it takes for granted what remains to be proved, that the U.S. really is "Babylon". When I see that assumption, I always suspect the influence of American particularism. As far as I can tell, "persecution" is so much an identifier of Revelation's Babylon that there is no rational reason to identify any entity as Babylon until the persecution starts happening.

Several Noes of Interpretation(1) The OT verses under consideration were fulfilled during OT history of the wayward Israel nation. No future fulfilment of this prophecy is hermeneutically necessary.

Therefore this is what the LORD of hosts says: "Because you have not obeyed My words,  behold, I will summon all the families of the north...and I will send for my servant, Nebuchadnezzar king of Babylon, whom I will bring against this land, against its residents...So I will devote them to destruction and make them an object of horror, an everlasting desolation. (Jeremiah 25:8,9)

The nation of Israel was conquered, and the Temple where God had placed His Name, was destroyed in 586 BC (BCE).
(2) Persecution of the Church could in no way be a "sign of the end times". Suffering persecution has been a hallmark of the LORD's people from the get go! Read the book of Acts about the first century Church, and what they endured.
Aldo, persecution could not be a "sign of the end times" because Jesus, the Master Teacher, taught that there were no signs concerning the Second Coming, or the end times. Read Matthew 24-25: Be ready because you do not know when....
(3) As already commented on, it is not safe to run to the most figurative, symbolic book in the Bible, to find interpretations about what Babylon means in relation to modern government! And unfulfilled prophecy remains pure speculation---if indeed, it is a prophecy! And not just an apocalypse with exhortative intent. (q.v. definition of "Apocalypse.")
Keep studying the Bible, and take more advantage of biblical research products: commentaries, lexicons, archaeology, biblical history, atlases, etc. It's great for the soul!
